# Block HTTP POST Upload

Tags: http, post

I'm working on a custom webserver and I was wondering if it's possible to send a http response before the browser starts sending the body?  Very important, I'd like to keep the connection open and if anybody's interested, the http response I'd like to send is a 509 (Bandwidth Limit Exceeded).

For now, it seems what I've been able to do is to prevent the server from downloading the body and it's trying to send the response back but the browser (Chrome) hangs at 'Uploading (0%)...'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could try a chunked upload, but standard http is basically "client sends request in its entirety, server responds with a complete answer". it's not "send a chunk, wait for reply" by default.

Comment: So one can't send the headers and then the server gets to send you some response?